# Видео из YouTube в андроид приложении

Tags: android, youtube

В некоторых приложениях есть функция  проигрывания видео не переходя в официальное приложение YouTube. Как это реализовать?Есть ли специальные библиотеки?Если реализация очень сложна, то как просто вставить видео из YouTube в приложение, даже , с условием , что оно будет проигрываться в официальном приложении?

Comment: У YouTube [есть API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) для Android

Comment: Я знаю, есть что-нибудь полегче?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

[http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/ ]

Тут ты найдёшь пример использования такого окна ютуба.

Там же найдёшь ссылку на целый проект. Ссылка называется

`download the completed project here`.

Чтоб проект заработал, тебе нужен api ключ, который ты должен создать в `console.developers.google.com`, тебе только гугл аккаунт нужен.

Там создай виртуальный проект,
 перейди по кнопке

`Enable APIs and get credentials like keys`

`YouTube Data API` - `Enable` кажется, кнопка сверху. Нажми её, далее слева вкладка

`Credentials`, далее на синюю кнопку `credentials`, выйдет подменю, там `android key`

`package name` - имя твоего проекта, типа `com.example.zaynulabid.myprojectname`

.
SHA-1 у меня такой

`39:A2:AB:DF:C9:A4:24:BB:19:0F:73:40:FC:99:08:4E:36:6B:FC:6D`, у тебя будет другой.
 Как тебе его достать: 
В андроид студио внизу есть окошко терминала,
напиши там команду для Mac OS X

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`

или

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias
androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

для Windows7:

`keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
 -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

**НО! это DEBUG CERTIFICATE**
Он для тестирования. Для выгрузки на маркет, он не подойдёт.
Для выгрузки на маркет нужен, кажется, "RELEASE CERTIFICATE".

Если выйдет строка

`Enter keystore password:`, впиши `android`

Выйдет куча строк. Найди "SHA1:" и содержимое скопируй и вставь в поле при создании апи ключа.
Когда создашь этот апи ключ, засунь его в тот проект, в класс

`Config.java`

P.S. Browser API нужен для отображения списка видео, а Youtube API нужен для самого плеера в приложении, он и должен считывать количество просмотров. В общем, браузер апи используем при подгрузке данных о списке видео, ютуб апи при воспроизведении через плеер.

Ещё, последнее. Надо скачать библиотеки ютуба. Отсюда

[https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/ ]

Распакуй архив в папку lib твоего проекта и 
в

`build.gradle`

в блок `dependencies` впиши строку

`compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

Чтоб расширить функционал, я поискал и добавил ещё парочку файлов. Тебе они по идее не должны понадобиться для этого проекта. Но если что, поищи в инете и скачай, тоже с офф сайта google

`compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.21.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.21.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.21.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.21.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.21.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.21.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')`

Если будете работать с каналом youtube, то нужен будет `browser api`, можно также создать в Credentials, где создавали youtube api ключ. При создании ключа, поля адреса для доступа пока оставить пустым(это ограничители для ключа).

Вот пример адреса к видео

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=[ID плейлиста]&key=[ключ browser api]`

У меня так:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUIQ6UDqSoWIEoGZ5tLJd1QA&key=AIzaSyDLMSSM79_......................BQ`

Если будете работать с проектом, на который я ссылался, то там будет класс плеера, в котором будет строка кода
`youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);`

Вот в YOUTUBE_API_KEY класса Config и надо вставить свой ютуб-апи ключ

Comment: извиняюсь, по незнанию написал, но оказалось, что для работы с youtube библиотекой нужен уже установленный youtube плеер. Понял это, когда установил своё приложение на андроид тв

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через `VideoView`:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);

String pathToVide = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";

Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(pathToVide);

videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
videoView.start();
```

Разметка:

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Еще, как вариант, можно использовать `MediaPlayer`.
Скорее всего вам он предпочтительнее в использовании.
По ссылке можете посмотреть реализацию.

Пример взят [отсюда.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888)

Comment: Спасибо большое.Сегодня попробую оба